# Regarding the Definition of Harmonic Current on a Compact Complex Manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-forms, distribution-theory, harmonic-functions, complex-manifolds

*Harmonic Currents of Finite Energy and Laminations*, *J. E. Fornaess* and *N. Sibony*, *Geometric And Functional Analysis*, $2005$, Page $965$, Section $2$ "Harmonic Currents".

Definition $2.1$

Let $M$ be a Compact Complex Manifold of (complex) dimension $k$. For $0\leqslant p,q \leqslant k$, let $T$ be a $(p,q)$ current on $M$ of order $0$. We say that $T$ is **Harmonic** if $i\partial \overline{\partial} T=0$.

The question is:

Is not it enough in the definition of Harmonic Current to say $\partial \overline{\partial} T=0$ (without $i$) that means the current is $\partial \overline{\partial} -$ closed? (Why did they add $i$ in the definition?).

[image]

Comment: ...Yes? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @ArcticChar Why did they add $i$ in the definition?

Comment: Try to check it for functions what is $\Delta f $ and what is $\partial \bar \partial f$? They are off by a $\sqrt{-1}/4$.